# Eval function for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I built a calculator and I am wondering how to handle the `eval()` function in jQuery. Is there any way to do it? Below, I wrote a javascript function that calculates and shows the result of the calculations. I would like to convert it to jQuery. Thanks in advance.

```
function result(val) {
    document.getElementById("resultBox").value = val;
}

function calc() {
    try {
        result(eval(document.getElementById("resultBox").value))
    }
    catch (result) {
        result('Error')
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.buttons').click(function () {
                $('#resultBox').val($('#resultBox').val() + $(this).val());
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please don't use `eval()`. Also, it has nothing to do with jQuery and what you have should work, but please don't use it. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: It would be no different with jQuery...

Comment: Please don't edit a new question when your edits need approval and you don't bring a significant improvement. You're preventing other edits.

Comment: I just want to make shorter my function and not try complicated things. I am new with js and improve this code later. So you say there is no way to do it with jQuery ?

Comment: @EminÇiftçi jQuery is just a library on top of JavaScript bringing adding some convenient functions. Your code is already compatible with jQuery (but you shouldn't use eval).

Comment: @DenysSéguret was the edit comment to me? Apologies if I over-wrote your changes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, it was to Caleb

Comment: `result($( '#resultBox' ).val());` would be what you want, although i don't understand the `calc()` method because it gets the resultbox and the `result()` method writes the resultbox with the same value because no calculations were made, and how is it supposed to know the result without result?

Comment: @KevinKloet "no calculations were made" => try `eval("2+2")`

Comment: @KevinKloet the calculus is done by `eval()`

Comment: i know eval can calculate...

Comment: @KevinKloet I added the my jQuery function that takes inputs

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the only things that would be changed are the `document.getElementById` functions, which would be changed to `$("#resultBox").val(val)` and `$("#resultBox").val()`, respectively.

As a sidenote, it would be better if you changed the variable that is named "val" because it creates slightly confusing code.